# React простая ошибка?

Tags: reactjs

```js
<script type="text/babel">

  function helloWorld() {
  return (
  <div>
   <h1>Hello world!</h1>
  </div>
  )
 }

 render(<helloWorld/>, document.getElementById('root'))
 
 
</script>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Hello World!</title>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.0/react.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.0/react-dom.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.6.15/browser.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <div id='root'></div>

 

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, покажите текст ошибки и минимальный пример, чтобы повторить её. См. также [mcve].

Comment: К сожалению, пока не понятно, в чём ваша проблема заключается. Но на всякий случай напомню, что названия собственных компонентов требуется писать с большой буквы. В вашем случае можно переименовать функцию helloWord. Подробности в документации [User-Defined Components Must Be Capitalized](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#user-defined-components-must-be-capitalized).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пример с созданием класса, с использованием стрелочной функции и с использованием обычной функции

```js
class HelloWorld extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return ( 
      <div>
        <h1> Hello world! </h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const Hello2 = (props) => {
    return ( 
      <div>
        <h1> Hello world 2! </h1>
      </div>
    );
};

function Hello3(props) {
    return ( 
      <div>
        <h1> Hello world 3! </h1>
      </div>
    );
}

ReactDOM.render( <HelloWorld /> , document.getElementById('root'));
ReactDOM.render( <Hello2 /> , document.getElementById('root2'));
ReactDOM.render( <Hello3 /> , document.getElementById('root3'));
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id='root'></div>
  <div id='root2'></div>
  <div id='root3'></div>
</body>

</html>
```